# Postgresql Rule vs Trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, rules

I looked up official documents and researched them, but I still don't know what to use in what situations. Could you tell me a simple example and the difference? What are the advantages of having to write a RULE?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894142/what-are-postgresql-rules-good-for

Comment: Why do you think that you need a RULE? What is your business case? I never used it and never missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about rules.

The Postgres Wiki recommends [to never use them](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_rules)

> Why not?
>
> Rules are incredibly powerful, but they don't do what they look like they do. They look like they're some conditional logic, but they actually rewrite a query to modify it or add additional queries to it.
>
> That means that all non-trivial rules are incorrect.
> Depesz [has more to say](https://www.depesz.com/2010/06/15/to-rule-or-not-to-rule-that-is-the-question/) about them.
>
> When should you?
>
> **Never.** While the rewriter is an implementation detail of VIEWs, there is no reason to pry up this cover plate directly.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>